# Decoding an image with Stegano Module

Tags: python, image, module, decode, steganography

I have a image file that i have to decode with Stegano module. I tried everything but always getting syntax error.

Error:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/Stegano-master# stegano-lsb reveal -i predat0r.png
Install Stegano: sudo pip install Stegano
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/stegano-lsb", line 32, in <module>
     from stegano import tools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stegano/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
     from . import red
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stegano/red/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
     from .red import*
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stegano/red/red.py", line 33
     def hide(input_image: Union[str, I0[bytes]], message: str):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfKDk.jpg this is the image that i have to decode.

What should i do now? Can someone help me with decoding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sudo pip3 install stegano
```

and then run it under python3.